# When decoding ASCII, should the parity bit be deliberately omitted?

Tags: python, character-encoding, character, ascii

According to Wikipedia, the ASCII is a 7-bit encoding. Since each address (then and now) stores 8 bits, the extraneous 8th bit can bit used as a parity bit.

> The committee voted to use a seven-bit code to minimize costs
> associated with data transmission. Since perforated tape at the time
> could record eight bits in one position, it also allowed for a parity
> bit for error checking if desired.[3]:217, 236 §5 Eight-bit machines
> (with octets as the native data type) that did not use parity checking
> typically set the eighth bit to 0.

Nothing seems to mandate that the 8th bit in a byte storing an ASCII character has to be 0. Therefore, when decoding ASCII characters, do we have to account for the possibility that the 8th bit may be set to 1? Python doesn't seem to take this into account — should it? Or are we guaranteed that the parity bit is always 0 (by some official standard)?

#### Example

If the parity bit is 0 (default), then Python can decode a character ('@'):

```
int('0b01000000', 2).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little').decode("ascii")
# Outputs: '@'
```

But if the parity bit is set to 1, then `byte.decode` fails:

```
int('0b11000000', 2).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little').decode("ascii")
""" Outputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    int('0b11000000', 2).to_bytes(1, byteorder='little').decode("ascii")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
"""
```

But the value of the 8th bit should not matter, since ASCII only uses 7 bits. Note: I'm not asking how to make `byte.decode` work with non-zero parity bits, but on whether it should be explicitly ignored by decoders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the parity bit CAN be set is just an observation, not a generally followed protocol. That being said, I know of no programming languages that actually care about parity when decoding ASCII. If the highest bit is set, the number is simply treated as `>=128`, which is out of range of the known ASCII characters.

Comment: I also thought that a language shouldn't care about the parity bit, but I took that to mean that a non-zero parity bit shouldn't make a difference (like causing an error). But in this case a non-zero parity bit will cause the program to crash.

Comment: Because it is possible to extend ASCII by adding 128 more characters to the set, such as the common special Europian characters. The whole byte is used and it is applicable to more domains. The pros of the fact that both of these sets share the first 128 character encodings are, among others, compatibility.

Comment: Yes, but that is no longer ASCII but something like ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1), which `byte.decode` is able to decode if you specify 'iso-8859-1' instead of 'ascii'. But in the question we are dealing with ASCII specification only.

Comment: So your proposed solution would be to duplicate the translation table from numbers `[0, 127]` to numbers `[128, 255]`, so that the table is twice as large and the "parity bit" is truly ignored? Apparently, not enough people would find this useful and hence it was disregarded.

Comment: You're obviously welcome to define your own superfast translation from bytes to parity ASCII using c/c++ and then binding into python. Expect, however, that this will fail for general ASCII files, as those honor the fact that the "parity bit" is not ignored, but set to `0`, supposedly precisely for the fact that you just need a 128 member sized array for translation from simple ASCII numbers to characters, not 256.

Comment: It could be implemented using a bitmask (AND 01111111 or XOR 10000000), but I'm not interested in how to implement it. I'm just asking whether an ASCII decoder should account for the possibility of a non-zero parity bit, or whether there's some other rule that it should always be 0 (so the decoder doesn't have to account for it).

Comment: Yes, I'm just wondering if there's some official guarantee that ASCII files will set their parity bit to 0 (Wikipedia's "typically" is not very helpful). Because in this case, the program/decoder will crash if it encounters a parity bit of 1.

Comment: @aiwl: ASCII is basically dead. Very, very few places actively and deliberately produce "ASCII output". Almost everyone uses either a fixed encoding like something from ISO-8859-* family or UTF-8 (with some preferring UTF-16). So if I *ever* see a text file where the 8th bit is set of some of the bytes, I'll assume it's one of those and NOT "ASCII with a paraity bit". If you hear hooves think horses, not Zebras! (swap around if you live in a place where Zebras are native).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks, I think I get what Captain Trojan and you are saying now. It throws an error because, although ASCII allows a non-zero parity bit (which is archaic), it is most likely that you are trying to decode some ISO-8859-* family as ASCII (so throw an error).

Comment: I've seen "ASCII with parity" employed in low level serial transmission. But even in these cases parity generation (what parity? even, odd?) and parity checking were done in hardware and the software only ever dealt with a zero topmost bit.